# Como mostrar una lista en vue.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js

componente del libro

```
<template>
<div :class="['book-item', { 'book-item--favourite': favorite }]">
    <button class="delete-book"><img src="../assets/delete-button.svg"></button>
    <div class="book-item__cover">
        {{ BookItem.cover }}
    </div>

    <div class="book-item__info">
        <h2 class="book-item__title">{{ BookItem.title }}</h2>
        <p class="book-item__author">{{ BookItem.author }}</p>

        <div class="book-item__data">
            <p class="book-item__year">{{ BookItem.year }}</p>
            <p class="book-item__pages">{{ BookItem.pages }}</p>
            <p class="book-item__genre">{{ BookItem.genre }}</p>
            <p class="book-item__editorial">{{ BookItem.editorial }}</p>
            <p class="book-item__language">{{ BookItem.language }}</p>
            <p class="book-item__isbn">{{ BookItem.isbn }}</p>
        </div>

        <p class="book-item__description">{{ BookItem.description }}</p>
        <p class="book-item__personal-note">{{ BookItem.personalNote }}</p>

        <div class="book-item__extra">
            <p class="book-item__price">{{ BookItem.price }}</p>
            <p class="book-item__stock">{{ BookItem.stock }}</p>
            <p class="book-item__rating">{{ BookItem.rating }}</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    name: "BookItem", 
    props: {
        id: {type:Number},
        title: {type:String},
        author: {type:String},
        year: {type:Number},
        pages: {type:Number},
        cover: {type:String},
        genre: {type:String},
        description: {type:String},
        editorial: {type:String},
        language: {type:String},
        isbn: {type:Number},
        price: {type:Number},
        stock: {type:Number},
        favorite: {type:Boolean},
        rating: {type:Number},
        personalNote: {type:String},
    },
}; 
</script>
```

componente de la lista de libros

```
<template>
  <div class="book-list">
    <div v-for="bookItem in books" :key="bookItem.id" :book-item="bookItem">
      <book-item :bookItem="bookItem"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import BookItem from './BookItem.vue';
export default {
  name: "BookList",
  components: { 
    BookItem, 
  },
  props: {
    books: Array,
  },
};
</script>
```

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class = "header">
      <img class="logo" alt="UOC logo" src="./assets/uoc-logo.png" />
      <div class="title">Find a book</div>
    </div>

    <BookList :books="books">
    </BookList>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BookList from "./components/BookList.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    BookList,
  }, 

  data(){
    return {
      books: ['1', 'mi primer libro']
    }
  }

};
```

buenas, necesitaría vuestra ayuda si tengo un componente donde tengo las propiedades de un libro y otro componente donde tengo una lista de cada item de libro, como puedo enviarle datos para que se muestre en pantalla desde app.vue ? supongo q le tengo q pasar un array con cada parámetro al componente de lista pero me sale la pantalla en blanco.
ya estoy pasandole un data y en ese array le tendria que pasar los 16 parámetros pero la pantalla esta en blanco , a lo mejor no se realizar alguna llamada